# Максимальный размер загружаемого файла в Java Servlets

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Устанавливаем ограничение размера файла в 30 мб:

```
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, 
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*30, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*60)
```

При попытке загрузить файл большего размера получаем не `IllegalStateException()`, как написано в документации, а вот это:

*Не удается получить доступ к сайту*

```
Веб-страница по адресу http://localhost:8080/page, возможно, временно недоступна или постоянно перемещена по новому адресу.
ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

Если размер файла не превышает ограничение, все отрабатывает корректно.

Если не ставить ограничение, а просто использовать аннотацию `@MultipartConfing` тоже всё отлично.

Как только ставим ограничением и грузим файл покрупнее вот такая вот проблема.

Любые советы?

Comment: а если вы не ставите аннотаци и попытаетесь загрузить файл больше чем 30мб - все ок будет?

Comment: @Andrew_Bystrow аннотацию мне нужно ставить, такая архитектура проекта. Но если я не устанавливаю в ней никаких переменных, а просто помечаю аннотацией, тогда все ок для любых файлов

Comment: я спрашивал это к тому, что может быть браузер перестает отвечеть на такие большие файлы

Comment: @Andrew_Bystrow если указать просто (@MultipartConfig)без проблем и 3 gb загружает

Answer (score 1):

Вот так, если на Спринге:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Обошел так:

1. MultipartConfig без параметров.

   ```
   @MultipartConfig()
   ```
2. В коде вешаем свою проверку:

   ```
   Part filePart = req.getPart("file");
   if (filePart.getSize() > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
       throw new Exception(ERROR_FILE_SIZE);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Если бы использовался **Spring**.

Добавляем бин **multipartResolver**, например так:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(ServletContext servletContext,
        @Value("${rootFolder}") String rootFolder,
        @Value("${tempFolder}") String tempFolder) throws IOException {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1024*1024*30);
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1024*1024*30);
    multipartResolver.setUploadTempDir(new FileSystemResource(rootFolder + tempFolder));
    multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    multipartResolver.setServletContext(servletContext);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

оно действует на все приложение, везде где встречается **multipart content**.